# How to setup nerd tree default directory

Tags: vim, nerdtree

Can anyone show me how to setup Nerdtree default directory ?

Everytime I open nerdtree it always point to my "documents and setting/user/"

How can I tell nerdtree to point to "D:/working/"

Thanks

Comment: This should be on superuser rather than stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

Add a custom mapping to your `~/.vimrc`:

```
nnoremap <F9> :NERDTreeToggle /path/to/directory
```

The `set autochdir` option may pick your interest, BTW.